# How to target a different control with a trigger?

Tags: wpf, xaml, events, triggers, styles

How can I click the button and then it set the `Value` of `txtNoOfVehicles` to `NULL` or `""`?

```
<dxg:GridControl ItemsSource="{Binding ShiftEntries}">  
    <dxg:GridControl.Columns>
        <dxg:GridColumn Header="No. of Vehicles">
            <dxg:GridColumn.CellTemplate>
                <DataTemplate>
                    <StackPanel>
                        <dxe:TextEdit x:Name="txtNoOfVehicles" Text="{Binding RowData.Row.NoOfVehicles}" Mask="\d{1,4}" MaskType="RegEx" NullText="Infinity" NullValue="{x:Null}" AllowNullInput="True" ShowError="False" />
                        <Button Content="Infinity" Margin="3" />
                    </StackPanel>
                </DataTemplate>
            </dxg:GridColumn.CellTemplate>
        </dxg:GridColumn>
    </dxg:GridControl.Columns>
</dxg:GridControl>
```

I researched style/data/event triggers, but all the examples I saw targeted the same control that had the trigger applied. I would like the trigger on the click of the button, and the target to be the `Text` property of the `TextEdit`.

I Tried:

```
<Button Content="Infinity" Margin="3">
    <Button.Style TargetType="{x:Type Button}">
        <Style.Triggers>
            <Trigger Property="IsPressed" Value="True">
                <Setter TargetName="txtNoOfVehicles" Property="dxe:TextEdit.Text" Value="{x:Null}" />
            </Trigger>
        </Style.Triggers>
    </Button.Style>
</Button>
```

Comment: if you binding to a view model, why aren't you just clearing the text at that point? Slap on a command onto the button and then clear the text of the property backing that row.

Comment: @TTY I never thought of that, good idea, but I still think triggers would be simpler if only it could see the textbox...

Comment: I think using Commands as TTY said is the best way to achieve your requirement.

Answer (score 1):

To answer your question you can do something like this

```
<StackPanel>
    <TextBlock Name="Block"  Text="Test"  />
    <Button Name="btn">
         <Button.Triggers>
             <EventTrigger SourceName="btn" RoutedEvent="Button.Click">
                  <BeginStoryboard>
                       <Storyboard>
                            <ObjectAnimationUsingKeyFrames Storyboard.TargetName="Block"
                                                                   Storyboard.TargetProperty="Text"
                                                                   >
                                <DiscreteObjectKeyFrame Value=""></DiscreteObjectKeyFrame>
                           </ObjectAnimationUsingKeyFrames>
                      </Storyboard>
                 </BeginStoryboard>
             </EventTrigger>
       </Button.Triggers>
    </Button>
 </StackPanel>
```